# Unable to upload documents to server using file upload control in asp.net c# web forms application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net c# web forms application that uses a file upload control to load documents to a specific folder.  The location to upload the file is ~\Assignments\assignment_docs.

The error code is:

> Could not find a part of the path
>   'E:\web\me\Assignments\assignment_docs\filename.xlsx'.

The following is the code behind:

```
protected void btn_fuc_assnmt_doc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int i = 0;
            string filename = fuc_assnmt_doc.FileName;
            if (fuc_assnmt_doc.HasFile)
            {
                while (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Assignments/assignment_docs/") + filename))
                {
                    i++;
                    filename = fuc_assnmt_doc.FileName + " (" + i.ToString() + ")";
                }
                fuc_assnmt_doc.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Assignments/assignment_docs/") + filename);
            }

            SqlConnection azunl_cnxn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=tcp:s09.winhost.com;Initial Catalog=XXXX;User ID=XXXX;Password=XXXX;Integrated Security=False;");
            {
                SqlCommand new_doc_cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert Into tbl_assnmt_doc(assnmt_doc_title, assnmt_doc_type, assnmt_doc_upld_by ,assnmt_doc_upld_dt, assnmt_doc_path, assnmt_doc_desc, assnmt_id_fk) Values(LTRIM(RTRIM(@assnmt_doc_title)), LTRIM(RTRIM(@assnmt_doc_type)), LTRIM(RTRIM(@assnmt_doc_upld_by)), LTRIM(RTRIM(@assnmt_doc_upld_dt)), LTRIM(RTRIM(@assnmt_doc_path)), LTRIM(RTRIM(@assnmt_doc_desc)), LTRIM(RTRIM(@assnmt_id_fk)))", azunl_cnxn);

                new_doc_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@assnmt_doc_title", assnmt_doc_title_txt.Text);
                new_doc_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@assnmt_doc_type", assnmt_doc_type_ddl.Text);
                new_doc_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@assnmt_doc_upld_by", System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
                new_doc_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@assnmt_doc_upld_dt", DateTime.Now.ToString());
                new_doc_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@assnmt_doc_path", Server.MapPath("~/Assignments/assignment_docs/") + filename);
                new_doc_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@assnmt_doc_desc", assnmt_doc_desc_txt.Text);
                new_doc_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@assnmt_id_fk", hdn_assnmt_id_fk.Value);

                azunl_cnxn.Open();
                new_doc_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                azunl_cnxn.Close();

                if (IsPostBack)
                {
                    assnmt_doc_title_txt.Text = "";
                    assnmt_doc_type_ddl.SelectedValue = "";
                    assnmt_doc_desc_txt.Text = "";
                    hdn_assnmt_id_fk.Value = "";

                    gv_assnmt_docs.DataBind();
                    lbl_new_doc_submitted.Text = ("Your new document has been successfully submitted.");

                }
            }            
        }
```

This works just as expected in dev on my localhost, but I get the error when I try it on my Winhost server.

Comment: Did you check write permissions on your server directory?

Comment: I do that through IIS right?  I am able to see my site in IIS, but I don't have "Application Pool" available under the site.  It's available when I look at my local host, it's just not there for the live site.  I don't know much about IIS so any additional help is appreciated.

Comment: Inspect "~/Assignments/assignment_docs/" with Windows Explorer, right click and check if there's Read Only option not selected.

Comment: Thanks JCM.  I'm not sure why, but I could see the assignment_docs folder on the production server, but I wasn't able to explore it - it wasn't found.  So I just sent all of the files over to the server again and after 2 attempts it now sees the folder and it works as intended.